# Ordenador bloqueado

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Estoy programando en R, ante este código:

```
# Cargar paquetes necesarios
setwd('C:/Users/jonas/Downloads')
# Leer el archivo RDS
df_agenda2030 <- readRDS("df_agenda2030.rds")

# Obtener el recuento de los autores
autores <- df_agenda2030$author %>%
  table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(author = names(.)[1], count = Freq)

# Calcular los porcentajes en importancia
autores <- autores %>%
  mutate(percentage = (count / sum(count)) * 100)
  
# Ordenar los autores por el recuento descendente
autores <- autores %>%
  arrange(desc(count))

# Crear el gráfico de barras con ggplot2
ggplot(data = autores, aes(x = author, y = count, fill = author)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       labs(x = "Autor", y = "Recuento", title = "Principales autores") +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

# Mostrar los resultados
print(autores)
```

El ordenador se queda bloqueado y con la marca de stop de la consola de rstudio en funcionamiento ¿alguien me podría decir el por qué?

Comment: Ejecuta línea a línea, ¿en cual de ellas queda esperando? ¿Podrias compartir un `str(autores)`? ¿Que es lo que buscas con `print(autores)`?